# x11vnc - How can I allow only certain users to have a VNC session

Tags: server, ssh, sudo, vnc

On my server, all but port 22 (ssh) are closed.  VNC is possible, but only with a VNC-over-ssh method.

Right now x11vnc is started `-forever` at boot.  With the right ssh tunnel, anybody can initiate a VNC session.  I would like VNC sessions to be possible only for a certain group of users (sudoers).

Non-sudoers have legitimate access to the machine via ssh, but how can I make sure that they are denied a VNC session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the -unixpw option to use the user's OS name/password to authenticate instead of a single shared VNC password.   The same option also allows you to specify a list of which users to allow.   There are also a couple of other variants of that option (-unixpw_nis & -unixpw_cmd) that offer more ways of hooking into the system security and doing something fancier.

The [X11VNC command-line options](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/x11vnc_opts.html) page will give you a taste of how they work.